# recreate system reserve partition after converting GPT to MBR

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, partition

I have a really odd situation and it's kind of hard to explain so I will start off with the intended end goal.

Purpose: Migrate a Hyper-V virtual machine to AWS EC2

Problem: After meeting all of Amazon's prereqs for the migration, my image import into EC2 is still failing

Hypothesis: Converting the disk from GPT to MBR may have messed up the structure of the disk

Here is a breakdown of my workflow:

- Mount the VHDX file to a Windows 8.1 system
- Convert the disk from GPT to MBR using AOMEI Partition Assistant(AWS only supports MRB disks formatted with NTFS)
- Launched a new Hyper-V virtual machine using the converted disk as the virtual hard drive source
- Inserted a Windows Server 2012 R2 ISO to the VM and booted into recovery
- Marked the main volume (c: drive) as active and ran the bootrec /fixboot, /fixmbr, and /rebuildbcd commands
- Booted into the VM and deleted the old recovery partitions from when the disk was GPT-based
- Import into AWS

Basically, the reason I am thinking the structure of the disk is the cause of the problem is I spun up a fresh VM with nothing installed other than the AWS Command Line tools (AWS prereq) using a Gen1 Hypervisor in Hyper-V and the import works flawlessly.

My next logical step was to try and recreate the 350MB MSR partition that Windows creates automatically on a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2 but I have a couple questions:

- How do I recreate this partition?
- It is normally 350MB but the empty space at the beginning of my disk (from deleting the old recovery partitions) is roughly 500MB